# Is there any function that plots Smith–Volterra–Cantor set

Tags: plot

I have found a function cantor() in the library geostats. This plots regular Cantor set. Is there any similar function to plot any Smith–Volterra–Cantor set?

Comment: Why not look it up in the documentation of the geostats package?

Comment: I did this and unfortunately there is not one. And I could not find anything in other packages so far, that is why I asked. Maybe someone knows better :)